# runnerw.exe: CreateProcess failed with error 5: Access is denied

Tags: windows, git, intellij-idea

I installed Git using Choco and checking where it is installed:

`C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core`

Problem here is setting this with VCS on IntelliJ throws:

`runnerw.exe: CreateProcess failed with error 5: Access is denied.`

How do you use git installed with Choco with IntelliJ? (*I don't think running IntelliJ as admin is a good idea*)

Comment: Use a tool like [ProcMon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to learn which file system object is attempted to be accessed. I'm pretty sure the real issue is a path with spaces that's not properly quoted rather than an actual access control problem.